# How do you make a file to read only in an ant build?

Tags: ant

I have an existing ant build file that zips up some files, but I want to make some files read only in the zip on osx and windows. Is this possible?

I've found you can change the read only attribute on windows with [<attrib>](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/attrib.html), but "Right now it has effect only under Windows". Any cross platform solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod` is the Unix-only way, but there is no cross-platform task.

But when you say you want to make the files read-only inside the ZIP then you don't need to modify the files on disk (in fact it wouldn't have any effect on the permissions stored inside the archive if you use Ant's `zip` task). In order to set permissions of archive entries, use a `zipfileset` and the `filemode` attribute. Something along the lines of

```
<zip ...>
  <fileset dir="...">
    <exclude name="files that should be read-only"/>
  </fileset>
  <zipfileset dir="..." filemode="444">
    <include name="files that should be read-only"/>
  </zipfileset>
</zip>
```

Comment: Oh, perfect `<zipfileset ... filemode="444">` was exactly what I needed. Thanks!